# Does iptables not work with long-named network interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ubuntu-16.04

I used to configure iptables to forward packages between different network interfaces on a muli-network-interface-server.

So long, it worked fine until I updated my server to Ubuntu 1604.

Ubuntu 1604 comes with the new kernal, which rename networkinterfaces([Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/))

Let's say, this server connects two sub-networks together:

- Interface `enp3s0` with ip `192.168.1.155`, connects to the network
  `192.168.1.0/24`,
- Interface `enxa0cec80f64f3` with ip `10.1.1.1` connects to the network
  `10.1.1.0/24`.

As bellow.

```
               Terminal1(10.1.1.2/24, gateway10.1.1.1)
                                 ||
                                 ||
                                 \/
                   +---------------------------+
                   | enxa0cec80f64f3(10.1.1.1) |
                   |                           |
                   |           Server          |
                   |                           |
                   |   enp3s0(192.168.1.155)   |
                   +---------------------------+
                                 /\
                                 ||
                                 ||
    Host1(192.168.1.111/24, route to 10.1.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.155)
```

To enable hosts in the 2 networks talk to each other freely, iptables on the server is configured as

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -i enxa0cec80f64f3 -o enp3s0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 10.1.1.0/24 -i enp3s0 -o enxa0cec80f64f3 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

The forwording does not work properly.

- *Host1* ping `192.168.1.155`, **SUCCEED**;
- *Host1* ping `10.1.1.1`, **SUCCEED**;
- *Host1* ping *Terminal1*(`10.1.1.2`), **FAILED**;
- *Server* ping *Terminal1*, **SUCCEED**

As i checked on the server with tcpdump, the packets from `enp3s0` side was not forwarded on. (For some reason, I can not just check the packets from the other side)

Maybe iptables does not works with long-named network interfaces like enxa0cec80f64f3?

Comment: That firewall does not actually block anything. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: What Michael says.  The correct test for whether forwarding is working is *whether you can see packets coming in one interface and going out of another*, with something like `tcpdump -n -n -i enxa0cec80f64f3 icmp`.  What happens after that might be a problem, but it's not a forwarding problem.   Just to catch an obvious gotcha, `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns `1`, yes?

Comment: @MadHatter I checked, with tcpdump and Wireshark. Server got ICMP from Host1(with desination Terminal1), but did not forward them.

Comment: @MadHatter It turns out I did not enable forwarding after the system installation, thanks for noticing. Please post your comment as an anwser.

Comment: @hxpax done, so that you may accept it!  Glad we could help.  (Don't feel bad, I've been setting up Linux routers for 20 years, and *still* once a year or so I forget to turn on the Big Forwarding Switch.  It's easily done.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right test for forwarding is *whether packets that present at one interface with a destination that would be accessed via another appear also on that other interface*, and the right way to test that is something like `tcpdump`.  Here is forwarding happening properly; traffic on the internal interface:

```
[me@router ~]$ sudo tcpdump -n -n -i em2 icmp 
[...]
07:03:55.490295 IP 178.18.x.139 > 178.18.123.145: ICMP echo request, id 56423, seq 1, length 64
07:03:56.491899 IP 178.18.x.139 > 178.18.123.145: ICMP echo request, id 56423, seq 2, length 64
```

and at the same time on the external:

```
[me@router ~]$ sudo tcpdump -n -n -i em1 icmp
[...]
07:03:55.490588 IP 178.18.x.139 > 178.18.123.145: ICMP echo request, id 56423, seq 1, length 64
07:03:56.492255 IP 178.18.x.139 > 178.18.123.145: ICMP echo request, id 56423, seq 2, length 64
```

If you don't see that, which in you case you do not, the first thing to check is `iptables`.  But as Michael Hampton has pointed out, your rules have *nothing* but `ACCEPT`s in them, so that can't be the problem.  You have also been advised to check the Big Kernel Forwarding Switch

```
[me@router ~]$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

which in your case returned `0` - meaning that no forwarding was enabled.  Correcting this, presumably by changing the relevant line in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and running `sysctl -p`, has fixed the problem.